# Memoization Function taking more time than non memoized one

Tags: javascript, memoization

I am trying to implement memoization technique in javascript. But my memoized function is taking more time than the non memoized function. I think I have implemented memoized function correctly (I am a newbie to programming).
Can anybody help and let me know the reason.

Memoized function code :

```
function fiboeven(n){
    var cache =[]
    if (n in cache)  return cache[n]
    else if (n === 1) return cache[0] = 2
    else if (n === 2) return cache[1] = 8
    else return cache[n] = 4*fiboeven(n-1) + fiboeven(n-2)
}
```

Non memoized  function:

```
function fiboeven(n){
    if (n === 1)
        return 2
    else if (n === 2)
        return 8
    else
        return 4*fiboeven(n-1) + fiboeven(n-2)
}
```

Comment: the cache should not be initialized in your function, otherwise it will always be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No your cache will be recycled after every call. And youre not really using it:

```
var cache=[0,2,8];
function fiboeven(n){
        if (cache[n])  return cache[n];
        return cache[n] = 4*(cache[n-1] || fiboeven(n-1)) + (cache[n-2] || fiboeven(n-2));
}
```

http://jsbin.com/fatoxivola/edit?console

The or operator ( || ) tries to take a cached value first, if it does not exist it generates it recursively.